# How do I replace tabs with spaces within variables in PHP?

Tags: php, replace, tabs, spaces

`$data` contains tabs, leading spaces and multiple spaces. I wish to replace all tabs with a space. Multiple spaces with one single space, and remove leading spaces.

In fact somthing that would turn this input data:

```
[    asdf asdf     asdf           asdf   ]
```

Into output data:

```
[asdf asdf asdf asdf]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to strip *all* tabs regardless or do you have any desire to columnar maintain formatting?

Comment: I think you should re-evaluate the answers and accept a different one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$data = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/g', '', $data));
```

Comment: You also forgot to mention trim to get rid of leading spaces. Probably want to mention ltrim too, since he asked for leading spaces then illustrated both ends.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that. In the example it's shown that both leading and trailing spaces should be removed so I updated my code.

Comment: helpful. [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) defaults to replace all occurrences of the pattern, unless you specify the limit parameter.

Comment: The "g" modifier doesn't seams to work. According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php no "g" is needed to repeat on the same line as the whole text, even if it contains newlines, is considered by php as one line

Comment: Typo - you are replacing spaces with '', but you wanted ' '.

Comment: minus one for a replacement string that removes ALL whitespace, even the single space that the OP wants between his "words"

Answer (score 24):

Trim, replace tabs and extra spaces with single spaces:

```
$data = preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}|[\t]/', ' ', trim($data));
```

Comment: First, this is a clunky pattern.  Second, as you wrote it, it doesn't rescan, and so it will produce multiple spaces for a run of `tab` `space` `tab` `space` `tab` `space`.  Did you test this?

Answer (score 5):

```
$data = trim($data);
```

That gets rid of your leading (and trailing) spaces.

```
$pattern = '/\s+/';
$data = preg_replace($pattern, ' ', $data);
```

That turns any collection of one or more spaces into just one space.

```
$data = str_replace("\t", " ", $data);
```

That gets rid of your tabs.

Comment: If you're using `\s` you don't need `\t`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the square brackets aren't part of the string and you're just using them for illustrative purposes, then:

```
$new_string = trim(preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $old_string));
```

You might be able to do that with a single regex but it'll be a fairly complicated regex. The above is much more straightforward.

**Note:** I'm also assuming you don't want to replace "AB\t\tCD" (\t is a tab) with "AB  CD".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I posted my answer just to refute your claim that trimming with `preg_replace` is "complicated".

Comment: Beauty answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_data = preg_replace("/[\t\s]+/", " ", trim($data));
```

Comment: if you're using `\s` you don't need `\t`

Answer (score 0):

This answer takes the question completely literally: it is *only* concerned with spaces and tabs.  Granted, the OP *probably* also wants to include other kinds of whitespace in what gets trimmed/compressed, but let's pretend he wants to preserve embedded <kbd>CR</kbd> and/or <kbd>LF</kbd>.

First, let's set up some constants.  This will allow for both ease of understanding and maintainability, should modifications become necessary.  I put in some extra spaces so that you can compare the similarities and differences more easily.

```
define( 'S', '[ \t]+'      ); # Stuff you want to compress; in this case ONLY spaces/tabs
define( 'L', '/\A'.S.'/'   ); # stuff on the Left edge will be trimmed
define( 'M',   '/'.S.'/'   ); # stuff in the Middle will be compressed
define( 'R',   '/'.S.'\Z/' ); # stuff on the Right edge will be trimmed
define( 'T', ' '           ); # what we want the stuff compressed To
```

We are using `\A` and `\Z` [escape characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) to specify the beginning and end of the subject, instead of the typical `^` and `$` which are line-oriented [meta-characters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php).  This is not so much because they are needed in this instance as much as "defensive" programming, should the value of `S` change to make them needed in the future.

Now for the secret sauce: we are going to take advantage of some special semantics of [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), namely *(emphasis added)*

> If there are fewer elements in the replacement **array** than in the pattern array, any extra patterns will be replaced by an empty string.

```
function trim_press( $data ){
    return preg_replace( [ M, L, R ], [ T ], $data );
}
```

So instead of a pattern string and replacement string, we are using a pattern array and replacement array, which results in the extra patterns `L` and `R` being trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to remove `&nbsp;` too.

```
$data = trim(preg_replace('/\s+|nbsp;/g', '', $data));
```

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration I found this to be the best solution, as it also removes non breaking spaces which can be two characters long:

`$data = html_entity_decode(str_replace('&nbsp;',' ',htmlentities($data)));
$data = trim(preg_replace('/\h/', ' ', $data));` // replaces more space character types than \s

See [billynoah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52062655/11827985)

Answer (score -1):

Just use this regex

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str));
```

it will replace all tabs and spaces by one space,

here sign `+` in regex means one or more times,
pattern means, that wherever there are two or more spaces, replace it by one space

Comment: minus one for a pattern that fails to match a solitary tab (and for not testing your solution before posting).