# PHP, Invalid characters in JSON decode

Tags: php, json

I'm having troubles getting json_decode to work on a specific string I am receiving.

I have narrowed it down to this line:

> "systemNotes[6]": "January 09, 2013 12:52 PM - Test Name - Changed  Billing Address 2 From  to Shipping First Name:    Shipping Last Name:     Email Address:  Shipping Address:   Shipping Address 2:     Shipping City:      Shipping Zip/Postal:    Shipping Country:   Shipping State:     Phone:      Billing First Name:     Billing Last Name:      Billing Address:    Billing Address 2:      Billing C"

Copying the json from this question, the problem is not reproducible - but a representative snippet of the original json is here: http://codepad.org/ZzrC7rqQ - and putting that in [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) gives:

```
Parse error on line 3:
...  "systemNotes[6]": "January 09, 2013 12
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

What is wrong with this string such that it's invalid json?

**EDIT**

I managed to find the exact code coming across.

> "systemNotes[6]":"January+09%2C+2013+12%3A52+PM+-+First+Name+-+Changed++Billing+Address+2+From++to+Shipping+First+Name%3A%09+Shipping+Last+Name%3A%09+Email+Address%3A%09+Shipping+Address%3A+%09+Shipping+Address+2%3A+%09+Shipping+City%3A+%09+Shipping+Zip%2FPostal%3A+%09+Shipping+Country%3A+%09+Shipping+State%3A+%09+Phone%3A+%09+Billing+First+Name%3A+%09+Billing+Last+Name%3A+%09+Billing+Address%3A+%09+Billing+Address+2%3A+%09+Billing+C"

This seems to be ok so maybe the problem is coming from when I do the parse_str, here's the code I am using:

```
$response = apiConnection($data);
parse_str($response, $parse);
$each = json_decode($parse['data']);
foreach($each as $key => $order){
   //do something
}
```

Comment: How are you collecting the string?

Comment: I am querying an API and it is sending it back to me as a string.

Which I am then using a parse_str on which leaves it in an array.

Comment: Could you check if the string has non-UTF 8 characters?

Comment: If it was a properly constructed json string, the tabs/spaces wouldn't matter.

Comment: I have tested it (after adding curly braces) and it seems to have no problem. Are you interested in the occult?

Comment: The issue doesn't paste properly in stackoverflow.  It seems to have turned those into plain spaces.  I am getting a better example.

Comment: It is hard to debug without walk through the raw JSON string. Since you could not paste actual JSON, just give details about api

Comment: Agree with @KaranAshar -- you should verify the whole string is UTF-8 encoded, at least to determine if it is the problem.  `mb_check_encoding($string, "UTF-8")`

Comment: Hey Karan and Jacob, that statement came back false for UTF-8.

Comment: THanks for that link AD7six: http://codepad.org/ZzrC7rqQ

Comment: I hope that the JSON string has tab instead space. Convert tabs in JSON string into space before doing json_decode(). Probably this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181559/how-do-i-replace-tabs-with-spaces-within-variables-in-php

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is the passed string generated? Is it under your control?

Comment: Because it is unclear: What is the response string? I guess that you meant the problem comes with json_decode and not parse_str.

Comment: This question is Unclear because we don't have a [mcve]. We have the input, but what is your desired output from that input?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that tab characters are not valid inside a string.

Removing the tab characters like here http://codepad.org/8fnQphkS and using that at jsonlint.com you will see it see now valid json.

Have a look at the specs for JSON at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627 specially section **2.5** where the tab character is called out by name as one of the characters that must be escaped if inside a string.

EDIT:

Here is a way of stripping out all tabs and multiple spaces and replacing them with a single space character:

```
$data = preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}|[\t]/', ' ', trim($data));
```

Comment: He would be better off decoding the json *before* he removes the url encoding, though.

Comment: `$data = preg_replace('/[\s]+|[\t]/', ' ', trim($data));` - all types of whitespace

Comment: If you are going to proceed with mutating the full string, then just replace one or more whitespace characters with a single literal space.  `'/\s+/', ' '`

Answer (score 6):

did you try something like that? it would help to clean your string

```
$yourstring = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $yourstring);
```